# Securing JSF applications

Tags: security, jsf-2

I've been asked by a freelancer friend of mine to join him on a JSF 2.0 project, and I'm slowly picking up speed and putting the pieces together. Coming from a Windows Forms .NET world, I have a lot to learn to say the least.

My major concern is with the lack of apparent consensus on how to protect a JSF application.

Some methods have been proposed here on SO, including using Spring security, Seam security, custom phase listeners, or simply using the `rendered="#{...}"` attribute to show/hide components based on user authentication.

I have tried to implement some of these methods, for example Spring security, only to find out that it gets easily defeated by the JSF navigation mechanism that forwards to views instead of redirecting. In other words, Spring security will work fine if the user types in the url of a secured page directly, but not if a `h:commandButton`'s action takes him there.

In view of this, some have suggested to force a redirect by using `"faces-redirect=true"`, but we feel that this could become a performance issue as this causes 2 requests from the browser each time.

On the other hand, I gave up trying to implement Seam security after getting so many missing dependencies errors.

The best solution I have found so far is a custom phase listener from [Duncan Mills - Effective Page Authorization In JavaServer Faces](http://duncanmills.sys-con.com/node/250254), but I'm not 100% convinced this should be used on public facing JSF applications.

So finally, what does this leave us with ? I know this is a pretty wide open ended question, but I honestly have no clue where to go next. I'm pretty sure I have followed the different tutorials to the letter, for example Spring tutorials, but I'm still not satisfied with the way it works.

Could anyone at least confirm/infirm the fact that Spring security is supposed to work across JSF forwards, as I've seen many posts by others having the same issue ? That would at least give me a direction to keep going.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Combination of servlet filter for page validation (applied to the faces servlet), identity session bean (storing user attributes e.g. Role, login id) and a few methods for entitlement checks (e.g. isAdmin(), canViewRecord(recordID)) well ised throughout your page.

You see, when it comes to security I opt for not leaving it in anybody else's hand. also, I validate in several places (hiding a component won't keep folks from forging the right POST request to trigger specific bean methods so watch out).

Comment: That is almost how I'm doing it, could be simple and safe.

Answer (score 0):

When I work with JSF I use spring-security.

About the behavior that you comment that spring security allows redirections done with commands button, is weird you must have a wrong configuration because it seams working fine in my project (I just tested).

In any case you can also use the spring security tags to render or not components according to the user's role.

This is a project that can help you to implement the tags.
http://www.dominikdorn.com/facelets/

Hope this helps..